# Adding new cookies with Mechanize Python

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2, mechanize

I am trying to add cookies to a browser in mechanize so I am not redirected to a click ok to agree page.

I have looked but can figure out how to do this.

I can do it using urllib2 already but wish to do it with mechanize

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'ASPSESSIONIDAEBDRQRT=HBODDIACJNHNMHNHBBIHOEGO; ASPSESSIONIDCEAATTSQ=ECNDDBKCJBMAHBIJOCJAEPEO'))

u = opener.open("https://www.transactionservices.dla.mil/daasinq/dodaac.asp")
```

How do I add that cookie string in mechanize?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using cookielib and Cookie built-in libraries to set cookies and append them to your mechanize session.

```
import Cookie
import cookielib
cookiejar =cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
cookie = cookielib.Cookie('ASPSESSIONIDAEBDRQRT=HBODDIACJNHNMHNHBBIHOEGO; ASPSESSIONIDCEAATTSQ=ECNDDBKCJBMAHBIJOCJAEPEO')
cookiejar.set_cookie(cookie)
```

AND Also, you can still add headers to your mechanize session:

```
br.addheaders = [('Cookie','cookiename=cookie value')]
```